# Linq to XML : Increase performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-xml

I want to read a xml file using Linq. This xml file is composed of 1 header and N Sub-Elements like this :

```
<rootNode>
         <header>
            <company name="Dexter Corp." />
         </header>
         <elements>
           <element>one</element>
           <element>eleven</element>
           <element>three</element>
           <element>four</element>
           <element>five</element>
           <element>three</element>
           <element>two</element>
           <element>two</element>
         </elements>
</rootNode>
```

I want to retrieve elements which are a value (example : two). And only if I retrieve elements, I get the header elements.

Today, I do like this :

```
        string xmlFilePath = @"C:\numbers.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);

        var header = doc.Descendants().Elements("header");
        var elements = doc.Descendants()
            .Elements("elements")
                .Elements("element")
                .Where(el => el.Value == "two");

        // I get this values even if there is no 'elements'
        string companyName = header.Descendants("company").Attributes("name").Single().Value;
        string serialNumber = header.Descendants("serial").Single().Value;


        return elements.Select(el => new {Company = companyName, Serial = serialNumber, Value = el.Value});
```

Is there a better way to parse the file ? (and increase performance ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If performance is important to you, you shouldn't use `doc.Descendants()` to look for an element at some known location. It always scans the whole document, which is slow if the document is big.

Instead, do something like

```
doc.Root.Element("header")
```

or

```
doc.Root.Element("elements")
        .Elements("element")
        .Where(el => el.Value == "two")
```

That should be much faster.